# Who has +1'd my posts in Google+

Tags: google-plus

In G+ new design, some +1s cannot be seen because some users makes it hidden. The question is how to know who have +1'd my posts (the full list). There is no special option is the new design of G+.

Comment: You can't override other users privacy settings.

Answer (score 2):

Of course you can see +1's and shares as they happen in your notification panel.

On the post itself, click the down arrow in the upper right corner and choose "View Post Activity".

There you'll see the +1's and shares for the post, excepting content from users who have blocked you or otherwise hidden their content from you, as it should be. ([h/t to batpigandme](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/44971/how-to-know-who-has-1d-my-posts-in-google-plus#comment35772_44971))

Comment: You're quite welcome, although the best way to convey "thanks" to someone here is to vote up their answer and, if it did indeed solve your problem, "accept" it. More on our [FAQ] and the [about] page.